# How do I know if I've written secure code?

Tags: php

I want to make sure that my users are secure. I've searched for the last 3 hours creating this system, but I'm honestly not sure. Could you glance at this code and see if I've compromised user data anywhere? The echo's are for debugging purposes.

```
class remember {
  public static $cookieSeperator = ' | ';

  public function generate() {
    global $conn;
    global $random;
    $userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $bytes = 24; //192 bit

    //Random generation code
    $token = $random->generateId('users', 'user_rtoken'); //Same as $prehash, but checks if there is a token already like this in the database
    $prehash = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes));
    $hash = hash('sha256', $prehash);

    echo $token . "<br />";
    echo $prehash . "<br />";
    echo $hash . "<br />";

    if (isset($_COOKIE['user_remember'])) {
      echo $_COOKIE['user_remember'];
    }

    //Cookie Code
    setcookie('user_remember', $token . self::$cookieSeperator . $prehash, time()+(86400*30)); //86400 = 1

    //DB code
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_rtoken='$token', user_rhash='$hash' WHERE user_id='$userID';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  }

  public function check() {
    global $conn;
    if (isset($_COOKIE['user_remember'])) {
      $cookie = explode(self::$cookieSeperator, $_COOKIE['user_remember']);

      $token = $cookie[0];
      $validator = $cookie[1];

      $sql = "SELECT user_rtoken,user_rhash FROM users WHERE user_rtoken='$token'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          if (hash('sha256', $cookie[1]) === $row['user_rhash']) {
            echo '0w0';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should read on using placeholders for your queries to prevent sql injection.

Comment: If the code works and you just want to know if there is a better way, you should post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @Joseph_J mysqi_real_escape_string?

Comment: google sql injection, and prepared statements

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related to another site:-[Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)